# Selecting from a table that contains: For each row in a different table call a table returning function

Tags: sql, t-sql

The title is pretty bad but heres the general idea of what I want to accomplish:

I have a table full of rows with IDs,
I also have a function that takes in those IDs and returns a table,
I would like to select a "master table" of all function returned tables from all the IDs

I understand I could do this easily with cursors but efficiency is a primary concern in solving this issue. I've tried several things with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

It sounds relatively simple so I am not sure if I am missing anything obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood the question, this should do it.

```
SELECT *
    FROM YourTable yt
        CROSS APPLY dbo.YourTableFunction(yt.ID)
```

Comment: Bah that is exactly it! I remember using Cross Apply forever ago and it doing the correct thing. Actually... I think it was you about a year ago haha. I didn't fully understand what it did, now I do. Lesson learned. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Karelzarath: An upvote from those who think the answer is worth accepting wouldn't hurt either. :-)

Comment: I was planning on it :) it made me wait a bit until I could mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  And a nod to 'Questions with similar titles' for directing me here ;)